# Java method to check if String includes special characters

Tags: java, compare, special-characters, string-comparison

I'm trying to write a Java code to check if password includes characters, numbers and special characters. Everything fine until the special characters part.
The idea is that the index of specialChars and the characters of the Password file are confront and, if there's a match, it would print a positive message, else it would throw an error.
But it returns both the positive message and the error. Not sure why.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher; 
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PasswordApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String filename = "C:\\Users\\gabri\\Desktop\\Generale\\Programmazione\\Java\\Password_Criteria\\Fakepassword.txt";

    File file = new File(filename);
    String Password = null;

    try { 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        Password = br.readLine();

        br.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
        System.out.println("ERROR: File not found: " + filename);
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        System.out.println("ERROR: Could not read the data: " + filename);
    }

    // Password valida: ha almeno un numero, una lettera e un carattere speciale

    try {
        String esitoPositivocarattere = "Carattere incluso.";
        String esitoPositivonumero = "Numero incluso.";
        String esitoPositivospeciale = "Carattere speciale incluso.";
        char[] specialChars = "!@#*+-_(%?/{}[].,;:".toCharArray();
        for (int n = 0; n < Password.length(); n++) {
            if (Password.substring(n).matches(".*[a-z].*")) {
                {
                    System.out.println(esitoPositivocarattere);
                }
            } else {
                throw new MissingCharacterException();
            }
            if (Password.substring(n).matches(".*\\d.*")) {
                System.out.println(esitoPositivonumero);
            } else {
                throw new MissingNumberException();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < specialChars.length; i++) {
                if (Password.indexOf(specialChars[i]) > -1) {
                System.out.println(esitoPositivospeciale);
            } else {
                throw new MissingSpecialCharacterException();
            }
        }
        }
    } catch (MissingSpecialCharacterException e) {
        System.out.println("ERRORE: Manca un carattere speciale.");
    } catch (MissingNumberException e) {
        System.out.println("ERRORE: Manca un numero.");
    } catch (MissingCharacterException e) {
        System.out.println("ERRORE: Manca un carattere.");
    }

}
}

class MissingSpecialCharacterException extends Exception { 

}

class MissingNumberException extends Exception {

}

class MissingCharacterException extends Exception {

}
```

Comment: I think `System.out.println(esitoPositivospeciale);` should be outside the `for` loop, otherwise you'll print it once for every character, until either the loop ends or the exception is thrown.

Comment: Fix your indenting to make the code more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say my password is "X3@" which fulfils the requirements for particular character types.

Now consider your password-checking loop, reformatted to better show the logic:

```
for (int i = 0; i < specialChars.length; i++) {
    if (Password.indexOf(specialChars[i]) > -1) {
        System.out.println(esitoPositivospeciale);
    } else {
        throw new MissingSpecialCharacterException();
    }
}
```

The very first character of specialChars is "!".  My password does not contain "!" so we do not print anything. Instead, we throw an error to say there's no special character in the password, obviously wrong.

You code thus requires that a password contains **all** special characters.  You need to rethink that logic.

The smallest change from what you write is something like this (not necessarily the most efficient, I'm just showing the way here):

```
boolean foundSpecial = false;
for (int i = 0; i < specialChars.length; i++) {
    if (Password.indexOf(specialChars[i]) > -1) {
        foundSpecial = true;
     }
}
if (foundSpecial) {
    System.out.println(esitoPositivospeciale);
} else {
    throw new MissingSpecialCharacterException();
}
```

Comment: Thank you access violation! It mostly worked, I just had to add a break code after sysOut to close the looping.

Answer (score 2):

When there's a "less code" way to achieve the problem, you'll have less bugs. Regex is your friend here:

```
public boolean passwordValid(String password) {
   return password.matches("(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[!@#*+_(%?/{}\\[\\].,;:-]).*");
}
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/wRoFQg).

Breaking down the regex:

- `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` is a [*look ahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that means "a letter appears somewhere later in the input"
- `(?=.*\\d)` is a look ahead that means "a digit appears somewhere later in the input"
- `(?=.*[!@#*+_(%?/{}\\[\\].,;:-]")` is a look ahead that means "a 'special character' appears somewhere later in the input".

Note that the hyphen has been moved to the last place in the character class to avoid it being interpreted as a *range*.

Comment: I think, where it's clear that the questioner doesn't quite understand code flow, an answer that presents another way entirely might not be the best approach.  Sure, he'll have code that works, but will he know why his original code **didn't** work?

Comment: @accessviolation I'm trying to say that the *approach* is OP's problem: More code means more chances for bugs.

Comment: I'm going to offer four cents here (two opinions).  Firstly, there are two ways to interpret this kind of question.  It's either _"why doesn't my code work"_ or _"give me code that works"_.  It's not clear which kind of answer OP would actually prefer - are they trying to understand what's going on, or do they just want to finish their task.  Certainly an answer to "why doesn't my code work" is likely to be more useful to others.  But also, I seriously disagree with Bohemian's assertion that more code gives more chances for bugs.  A somewhat opaque regular expression has WAY more chances ...

Comment: ... for bugs than a straightforward series of `if`, `else` and `for` constructs; and if there ARE bugs, they'll be much harder to find.  At least the approach that Access Violation has espoused can be debugged easily, as well as being easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: @Bohemian - I strongly disagree.  It's the **clearest** code that is more likely to have the fewest bugs, not the shortest.  Especially for a beginner, which I believe the OP is. My claim, then, is that the simple loop on 'if-else' is **clearer** (to a beginner) than a regular expression using multiple instances of zero-width positive lookahead,